# Linq SkipWhile method is not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq

I trying to write a program using Linq SkipWhile() method, output is not as expected. and not to use orderby method for sorting.
Here is my Program:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<int> numbersList = new List<int>(){ 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3 };
        
        var result = numbersList.SkipWhile((x, i) => i > 4 && x > 4);
        
        foreach(var num in result)
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        
    }
}
```

Output
1
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
2
3

am i doing something wrong in this program?

Expected Output
8
9
10

Comment: Maybe you prefer: `numbersList.Skip(5).Where(i => i > 4)`. It's clearer to me. It's as efficient as just using `Where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SkipWhile` - skips the elements of the sequence as long as they satisfy its condition, and then returns all the remaining elements.

In your example, already the first number in the sequence does not satisfy the requirement (1 < 4), so it just returns the entire sequence.

For your expected result, you can use two options:

```
var result = numbersList.OrderBy(x => x).SkipWhile(x => x < 8);
var result2 = numbersList.Where(x => x >= 8);
```

Comment: "until they satisfy its condition" - on the contrary: **while** the condition is met or equivalently: until the condition is **not** met.

Answer (score 1):

`SkipWhile` is not what you want for that output - `SkipWhile` will skip while the expression is true, and then *return everything else*. I think you just want `Where` with the additional index parameter:

```
    IList<int> numbersList = new List<int>(){ 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3 };
    
    var result = numbersList.Where((x, i) => i > 4 && x > 4);
```

Note that the reason you get the first 5 numbers in your current output is that `i > 4` is false until index 5, so the expression would return `false` and *not* skip until then.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a `.Where(` clause for your described output ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-7.0

Note:
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=net-7.0

> Bypasses elements in a sequence as long as a specified condition is
> true and then returns the remaining elements.

Here I changed `1` to `13` just to illustrate the index is considered;.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<int> numbersList = new List<int>(){ 13, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3 };
         foreach(var num in numbersList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"num:{num}");
        }
        
       var result = numbersList.Where((x, index) => ( index > 4 && x > 4));
        
        foreach(var num in result)
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
num:13
num:4
num:5
num:6
num:7
num:8
num:9
num:10
num:2
num:3
8
9
10
```